# Workflow for app variants targeting different versions of Flash Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I'm targeting Flash Player 10+ in my application. For Flash Player 10.3+, I'd like to use the `EnhancedMicrophone` capabilities introduced in 10.3. The difference between the app variants will thus be a couple of lines of code.

Should I create and maintain two separate projects in Flash Builder (and copy any changes from one to the other), or there's a smarter way? Some kind of "preprocessor directives" perhaps that would turn on/off blocks of code depending on the target player?

Comment: Look into using Conditional Compilation: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compilers_21.html . I'm not sure if it it'll work, but I think it will "Conditionally" compile code into your final project.  You'll have to create different "builds" for different versions, but at least you'll be able to do so from the same code base.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Looks like I should use conditional compilation in conjunction with Ant tasks to create those different builds.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give the version of the player :

```
var versionNumber:String = Capabilities.version;
trace(versionNumber);
```

For me on windows it traces this :

```
WIN 11,5,502,146
```

You can parse that and get the 11,5 part for the major/minor version and execute code based on that.

Comment: I don't think this is going to help, as this is a runtime function.  How does someone compile an app to run on Flash Player 10.0 while accessing classes that weren't introduced until 10.3?  Won't he get compile errors?

Comment: You're right this won't help at compile time. Seems like he would have to create different swfs after all.